# Implement List with value and text?

Tags: android, listview, xml-parsing

i am new to android. I have some doubt with list. I need to create a list dynamically from one the xml file.
The xml contains the format something like `<location id ="some_id" label="label">`(like `<option>` in html).
How can i represent this with list(or any other option. the locations should look like a list and i  want to  select this locations).
This id is used when the data is save back in server. I tried with list but cant get

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 parts to this

first, you need to either parse your xml file, or change the format to include it in the resources of the project as a string array (for instance) in your values.xml file

second, you need to set an alert with items corresponding to your values. see http://malsandroid.blogspot.com/2010/04/list-picker-and-fading-popup-notice.html

Comment: I don't understand the concept For string array it only contains the label. I want to attach the id to it. ie, when i select the label it should give the id. id is not the index of the array. it is coming from xml. so it not have an order..